# Fetch JSON React to PHP

Tags: php, json, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I created a button in React allowing me to store the data in a JSON by using Fetch and send it to a local PHP server as well.

I receive a call from my PHP file but I can't get the data.

Here is the React :

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
  };
  fetch('http://localhost:8000/index.php', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ postId: data.id }));

};
```

And here the PHP (I only try to print values) variables are always empty

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
error_log(print_r($_REQUEST, true));
error_log(print_r($_SERVER, true));
error_log(print_r($_POST['title'], true));

$var = $POST['title'];
error_log(print_r($var, true));
return;

}


if ($_REQUEST) {
error_log(print_r("omg", true));
return;

}

if (isset($_POST)) {
    echo print_r($_POST,true);
    return 0;
}
```

I also have the following error in React when I send the data.

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
> at :54:23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't return any JSON as expected by `response.json()`.

You can get your incomming data using `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

```
// prepare data to return
$dataToReturn = [];

// populate the data as you need
$dataToReturn = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

// Output the JSON string with appropriate header
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($dataToReturn);
exit(0);
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, I still got the same problem.
$DataToReturn is still empty

Comment: What is the output of the PHP (in your Network console)?

Comment: I copy your sample of code and add a "error_log(print_r($dataToReturn, true));" to get the data, it returns me an empty array

Comment: Did you check `file_get_contents('php://input')` data? You will have you JSON encoded data.

Comment: Perfect ! It works! thank you a lot